# Understanding ASP.net tracing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure I understand how to read tracing. Can someone shed some light on this for me?

If I see this:

```
Event         From First    From Last
Begin Load    0.016423      0.000006
End Load      10.201956     10.185533
.... 
Begin Render  10.477927     0.000006
End   Render  10.528951     0.051025  (This is last line)
```

I have absolutely no idea how to read this :( What does this mean? Do I read from left to right? Top to bottom? Do I read it from each "pair"? For example "begin render" and "end render" took the difference (10.52 - 10.4)

I want to see how long my page took in general, and then see how long each event took. The MSDN page didn't shed any light on this for me / made me more confused.

Also, why are these times different (worse) than Firebug's output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read it both top to bottom and left to right. Each row corresponds with some sort of event, and the fields in the row are the time it took to run.

If we look at the first row, `Begin Load` marks the start of the `OnLoad` event (this is when `Page_Load` gets hit). The first field, `From First` marks the total time since the time the request initially hit the server, so in this case `0.016423` seconds. `From Last` marks the time since the last event. Since `Begin Load` was the first event to be traced that is 0 since there is no previous event to compare to. `End Load`, which marks when the `OnLoad` even is completed, took `10.201956` seconds from the initial request, and took `10.185533` seconds from the previous event traced, which is the `Begin Load` event. This essentially says that your `OnLoad` event (and therefore `Page_Load` method) took 10 seconds to run.

As another example, let's look at `Begin Render`. It took `10.477927` seconds from the time the request hit the server until the `Begin Render` event was raised. It took `0.000006` seconds from the previous event (whatever that was, you didn't include it so I can't say). `End Render` took `0.051025` seconds from the previous event, which was `Begin Render` so your render event took ~0.05 seconds.